# Get instance of AuthenticationManager Manually

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement the below, but my authenticationManager instance throws the below exception and is not autowired.  How do I get an instance of it from Spring manually?  I'm not using a spring controller, I'm using a JSF request scoped bean. I get the below exception at runtime when the container tries to autowire the authenticationManager.  The requestCache comes in fine.  I don't understand why I have two instances...

config:

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

> Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]
>       javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)

```
@Controller
public class SignupController
{

    @Autowired
    RequestCache requestCache;

    @Autowired
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/signup/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result,  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //After successfully Creating user
            authenticateUserAndSetSession(user, request);

        return "redirect:/home/";
    }

    private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(User user,
        HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

        // generate session if one doesn't exist
        request.getSession();

        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
        Authentication authenticatedUser = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: Arr you saying the `authenticationManager` field is null? Is `requestCache` wired OK?

Comment: @skaffman thanks for the reply, I updated my questions a bit with some more info.  What I posted prior was not correct, its not null.  The container says I have two instances of the authenticationManager but I don't see how. I pasted my config above as well, any ideas? I'm just trying to do a auto login after successful registration.    Do I need to user my userManager to auto login?  userManager doesn't have a method that takes a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, provide an explicit bean name for your `AuthenticationManager`

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   ...
</authentication-manager>
```

Second, use qualifier when auto-wiring:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Comment: @Xorty With no alias you should guess the auto-generated name for authentication manager bean (I'm not sure at all it has a name by default). In theory, it might work if you use binding by type and not by name, though this is rarely case in real world systems.

Comment: @BorisKirzner how can I use this to autenticate my user object because i need to receive the user from a mobile device on httprequest and authenticate it and send the session Id as token

Comment: @B.TIger It is not so clear what is the problem you are trying to solve. I would recommend opening a separate thread, as it sounds to me that it is not related to the original question.

Comment: Please note: I was using the `id` attribute in addition to `alias` and that caused issues. Make sure you only use `alias`.