# @autowired Auth security:authentication-manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Here is my context file:

```xml
<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


<context:component-scan base-package="net.myrest.resources" />
```

I am trying to autowired Authentication Manager to `myrest.resource.file` but each time it gives me null.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
private AuthenticationManager authManager;
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as how you ran the code and how you found it null. More code please.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417509/get-instance-of-authenticationmanager-manually**

check this Link

Comment: What is `myrest.resource.file`?