# Autowiring Spring AuthenticationManager Filter always gives null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to use Spring Security's AuthenticationManagerBean inside a custom filter, but it seem to always give a null. I am using spring boot 1.3.8. Here is a snippet from the code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    

        @Override
        @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
     
     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       
     }
     
    

}
```

The filter code:

```
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
  private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

  @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    

    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
       
            //some checks

Authentication receivedAuthentication = tokenExtractor.extract(request);
receivedAuthentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                authenticationManager.authenticate(receivedAuthentication);
                 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(receivedAuthentication);
            
        }
    }
    
    

}
```

An exception is thrown because authenticationManager is null.

Comment: Have you read that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417509/get-instance-of-authenticationmanager-manually or that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter ?

Comment: Have you read that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter) or that one [Get instance of AuthenticationManager Manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417509/get-instance-of-authenticationmanager-manually) ?

Comment: Have you read that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter) or that one [Get instance of AuthenticationManager Manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417509/get-instance-of-authenticationmanager-manually) ?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that as well, still null

Answer (score 0):

The value of `BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER` is *"org.springframework.security.authenticationManager"*; therefore, you do not have a bean named *"authenticationManager"*.

Also, I think you need @Component on your Filter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it's still giving null though. I also tried using `@Qualifier` with `@Autowired`, but same thing.

Comment: I think your Filter needs @Component. And I take back my suggestion of renaming the method; I missed that it was overriding an existing method.

Comment: It did not change much, thanks anyway, I found another way to set authentication.